# PHP MySQL insert if not exist on keys in relation table

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am new at MySQL language. I find some troubles on inserting the relationship data. I have a table for storing user friendship. lets say user1(id =1) and user2(id =2)
are friends. then, I store the information in friend table like this:

friend table

```
user_id1 | user_id2
  1           2
```

However, some operations in my php file may check again these two users relationship and then insert / update the friendship information .

1) checking user with user_id1 and then update the friendship information (using insert ON DUPLICATE KEY).

```
INSERT INTO friend (user_id1, user_id2) VALUES ('1', '2') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE user_id2=user_id2
```

The friend table is still correct because nothing has been changed:

friend table

```
user_id1 | user_id2
  1           2
```

But if the checking starts from user2 first, the friendship information is inserted again

friend table

```
user_id1 | user_id2
  1      |    2
  2      |    1
```

Does any SQL statement prevents this situation happening?

Thank for answering and sorry for my bad English

Comment: You might be able to check for this with a trigger.

Comment: try if else IF  (EXISTS(SELECT * FROM friend WHERE (user_id1 = '1' and user_id2='2') or (user_id1 = '2' and user_id2='1'))) THEN
 
ELSE
 INSERT INTO friend (user_id1, user_id2) VALUES ('1', '2') 
END IF;

Comment: @Barmar
thanks for your comment. but I don't know how to create trigger. I will try it later.

Comment: @user1702477 It does not work on mysql_query() function which I want to implement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For SQL it is just new data, when in this case 1,2 is actually the same as 2,1. I don't know if there is a SQL function for this. But it might be appropriate to check the values in php before sending them to SQL.

Not knowing your PHP code, you could try something like this

```
$data = array('user_id1' => 2, 'user_id2' = 1);
arsort($data); //now the lowest id is always first

$user_id1 = current($data);
$user_id2 = next($data);

//send to SQL
```

Hope this can lead you in the right direction

Comment: you mean that I should always let the lowest id be inserted first? That is the great idea. Thanks!